# is this GraphQL query valid?

Tags: graphql

Assume a simple schema like

```
interface Character {name:String!}
type Human implements Character {name:String!}
type Droid implements Character {name:String!}
type Query {
  characters: [Character!]
}
```

This query is not valid because it does not select down to leaf (scalar) fields (see https://graphql.github.io/graphql-spec/draft/#sec-Leaf-Field-Selections):

```
{characters {
}}
```

Is this query valid? It selects a scalar field, but only for Human. It'd return Droids without any fields.

```
{characters {
   ... on Human {name}
}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Copying response from [issue](https://github.com/graphql/graphql-spec/issues/610))

Actually, I think that it is valid. The spec says :

> - If selectionType is an interface, union, or object
>
> The subselection set of that selection must NOT BE empty

It simply states that it must contain a subselection (could be an inline fragment as in your example). It doesn't specify that its subselections must be leaf field selections.

I agree that in essence it should actually contain leaf selections for every possible subtype of the field's return type (e.g `Human` and `Droid` in your scenario), otherwise it could return an empty response. For instance, if there are no humans and 3 droids in your database then it would return:

```
{
    "character" : [{}, {}, {}] 
}
```

This also happens with union types, you are not obliged to specify each concrete type and therefore can get empty results.

I imagine there must be some reason related to fragments ?

Comment: Thanks for the answer! But I imagine this is just yet another under-thought aspect of GraphQL. There are many gaps/defects in the GraphQL spec, and unfortunately the community is not moving forward to resolve them.